# BigQuery how to ommit data based on multiple results

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that will bring back results similar to below

| Account Number | Contract | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 0123 | Live |
| 000001 | 0124 | Live |
| 000001 | 0125 | Dead |
| 000002 | 0125 | Dead |
| 000002 | 0125 | Dead |

What I want to do is omit all results if at least one in the group with the same account number is "Live"

so my result should look something like this, omitting account 00001 alltogether as there is at least 1 live contract within it

| Account Number | Contract | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000002 | 0125 | Dead |
| 000002 | 0125 | Dead |

Is this possible and how would I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select *
from your_table
qualify countif(Status = 'Live') over(partition by AccountNumber) = 0
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]